# SQL for Desktop Application Vs SQL for Client Server Applications [IBM ProveIt Test]

Tags: sql

I recently heard about two SQL tests that **IBM ProveIt** platform offers - ***SQL Test for Client Server Applications*** and ***SQL Test for Desktop Applications***.

I am wondering if there any differences in SQL for client server applications and SQL for Desktop applications in general ?

Also, please let me know what to expect in these tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the test - SQL for Desktop Applications, it's all related to testing your knowledge on SQL statements - DDL/DML/Joins/Keywords. Nothing beyond SQL.